# Which file should I edit to change the breadcrumbs starting point?

Tags: magento

I wanted to change the breadcrumbs starting point from Home to My title. I edited the file  `/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Breadcrumbs.php` but it doesn't seem to be working. Is XML playing a role in that?

thanks

Comment: can you post the edits that you made?  before and after shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to use Magento's translate feature.  Notice how the text in `Breadcrumbs.php` is wrapped with `->__('text')` which instructs Magento to see if there is a translation for `text` for the current module.  If you turn on Translate Inline in `System>Config>Admin>Developer`, you will be able to edit the text on the page (after refreshing, click the red box then the little book icon).  This will then be entered into the database in the `core_translate` table and replaced in future page renders.

As a general rule, you should never edit files in `app/code/code` as you will break future upgrades and patches.

Comment: 1 last Question is the Modules the only thing that are editable when i enable this Option or what else can be edited by enabling this option

Comment: you're welcome.  Once you turn on Translate Inline, all the available text strings are highlighted with those red boxes.  Basically, they will be strings that are hard-coded into Blocks, Controllers or Helpers, either within the Magento core, or community extensions.  Text that comes from CMS Pages or Static Blocks is not editable using Translate Inline.

Answer (score 0):

turn on Translate Inline in System>Config>Admin>Developer, you will be able to edit the text on the page (after refreshing, click the red box then the little book icon)